# How to install node_modules on the time of electron app package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder

you can see the [image] I packed my electron app with electron-builder command.
But after installing that app its shows that node module not installed. how can I do that.

Comment: I think you added puppeteer as dev dependencies. Check you package.json. you should add puppeteer to dependencies if the electron app need it in runtime.

Comment: Welcome! Could you add some minimal reproducible code? In that way it's easier for us to help you out.